# requestAnimationFrame in polymer

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, polymer

I'm trying to implement an thrre.js animation on polymer with the code below. I can render the scene the first time, but when I call requestAnimationFrame(animate) - i.e. I call the function animate itself - then the code brake because it can't find any variable defined before. I know that requestAnimationFrame() accepts 2 parameters: the function to call and the element on which to call the function. I tried many different element without success.
Does anyone have any idea? thanks a lot.

```
(function(root) {

'use strict';

Polymer('x-trial-objects', {

    app : document.querySelector('x-app'),


    container : null,
    scene : null,
    camera : null,
    renderer : null,
    controls : null,
    stats : null,
    keyboard : new THREEx.KeyboardState(),
    clock : new THREE.Clock(),
    cube : null,
    parameters : null,
    gui : null,

    // Trial params
    dimensionChoice : 1,
    speed : 0.007,
    spikeNum : 3,
    radiusChange : 0.02,
    minLength : 1,
    maxLength : 3,
    rangeLength : 2,
    eventOccur : 1,
    ang : [-40, -95, 170, 40],

    getRandomInt : function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    },

    timeOcc : function timeOcc(speed){
        // Create array of possible times at which the event could occur, based on the rate of change (speed variable)
        var _this = this,
            timeArray = [],
            i;

        for (i=10;i<1/speed;i+=1) {
            // this adds all possible steps of the dimension and rounds to 3 decimals
            // Update - this now only allows the event to occur after the first 10 time steps to give subjects time to actually see the stimulus before the change
            timeArray.push(  Math.round((i*speed)*1000) / 1000  );
        }

        // Select a random timepoint in that array as the onset time of the event, and a timepoint N points beyond for the offset.
        var t1 = _this.getRandomInt(0,timeArray.length-1),
            t2 = t1+7;

        return [timeArray[t1],timeArray[t2]];
    },

    sigmoid : function(x,t) {
        // scale the x parameter by the temperature parameter
        var x=(x*t*2)-t;
        // calculate sigmoid
        return 1 / ( 1 + Math.exp(-x) );
    },

    quadratic : function(x) {
        // rescale the x parameter between -1 and 1
        x=(x*2)-1;
        // Calculate quadratic
        return x*x;
    },

    init : function (){
        var _this = this
        console.log(this)
        console.log(document)
        // Note that I could have a purely random number between 0 and 1 on each trial, but here I am specifically sampling from just 10 points along the dimension. This (a) ensures a good sampling across the whole dimension over trials and (b) allows us to constrain the sampling to certain parts of the dimension so that we can later test stimuli that were not presented in this phase. I may want to change this so that the overall experimental script deals with the randomisation. That way I can have better control over the sampling so that e.g. I have 10 points along the dimension, each sampled the same number of times over trials. At present i do not have this level of control, as every time the script is called it will pick one of these at random.

        var dimensionPoints = [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1];


        if (_this.dimensionChoice===1){
            _this.k1 = 0;
            _this.k2 = dimensionPoints[_this.getRandomInt(0, dimensionPoints.length-1)];
        }

        if (_this.dimensionChoice===2){
            _this.k1 = dimensionPoints[_this.getRandomInt(0, dimensionPoints.length-1)];
            _this.k2 = 0;
        }

        // SCENE
        _this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
        // CAMERA
        var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth, SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
        var VIEW_ANGLE = 45, ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR = 0.1, FAR = 20000;
        _this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
        _this.scene.add(_this.camera);
        _this.camera.position.set(0,0,10);
        _this.camera.lookAt(_this.scene.position);
        // RENDERER
        if ( Detector.webgl )
            _this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias:true} );
        else
            _this.renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
        _this.renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        _this.container = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#ThreeJS')
        _this.container.appendChild( _this.renderer.domElement );
        // EVENTS
        THREEx.WindowResize(_this.renderer, _this.camera);
        THREEx.FullScreen.bindKey({ charCode : 'm'.charCodeAt(0) });
        // CONTROLS
        _this.controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( _this.camera, _this.renderer.domElement );
        // STATS
        _this.stats = new Stats();
        _this.stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
        _this.stats.domElement.style.bottom = '0px';
        _this.stats.domElement.style.zIndex = 100;
        _this.container.appendChild( _this.stats.domElement );
        // LIGHT
        var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 );
        var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xFFFFFF, 1.0 );
        light.position.set( 200, 400, 500 );
        var light2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xFFFFFF, 1.0 );
        light2.position.set( -500, 250, -200 );
        _this.scene.add(ambientLight);
        _this.scene.add(light);
        _this.scene.add(light2);


        //Create central sphere
        var radius = 0.6;
        var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( radius, 32, 16 );
        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: "grey" } );
        var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        //Add the sphere to object spikedBall
        _this.spikedBall = new THREE.Object3D();
        _this.spikedBall.add( sphere );

        // Note that I can no longer loop through these four spikes, as I want to be able to scale each one independently after adding them to the scene
        var cylGeom = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 0, 0.3, _this.minLength, 32 );
        var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh( cylGeom, material );
        cylinder.position.y=_this.minLength/2;
        _this.spike1 = new THREE.Object3D();
        _this.spike1.add(cylinder);
        _this.spike1.rotation.z = _this.ang[0] * Math.PI/180;
        _this.spike1.scale.y = (_this.k1 * _this.rangeLength) + _this.minLength;
        _this.spikedBall.add( _this.spike1 );


        var cylGeom = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 0, 0.3, _this.minLength, 32 );
        var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh( cylGeom, material );
        cylinder.position.y=_this.minLength/2;
        _this.spike2 = new THREE.Object3D();
        _this.spike2.add(cylinder);
        _this.spike2.rotation.z = _this.ang[1] * Math.PI/180;
        _this.spike2.scale.y = (_this.sigmoid(_this.k1,7) * _this.rangeLength) + _this.minLength;
        _this.spikedBall.add( _this.spike2 );

        var cylGeom = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 0, 0.3, _this.minLength, 32 );
        var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh( cylGeom, material );
        cylinder.position.y = _this.minLength/2;
        _this.spike3 = new THREE.Object3D();
        _this.spike3.add(cylinder);
        _this.spike3.rotation.z = _this.ang[2] * Math.PI/180;
        _this.spike3.scale.y = (_this.k2 * _this.rangeLength) + _this.minLength;
        _this.spikedBall.add( _this.spike3 );

        var cylGeom = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 0, 0.3, _this.minLength, 32 );
        var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh( cylGeom, material );
        cylinder.position.y=_this.minLength/2;
        _this.spike4 = new THREE.Object3D();
        _this.spike4.add(cylinder);
        _this.spike4.rotation.z = _this.ang[3] * Math.PI/180;
        _this.spike4.scale.y = (_this.quadratic(_this.k2) * _this.rangeLength) + _this.minLength;
        _this.spikedBall.add( _this.spike4 );

        //Add spiked Ball to the scene
        _this.scene.add( _this.spikedBall )

        console.log(_this.scene)
    },

    render : function() {
        var _this = this;

        _this.renderer.render( _this.scene, _this.camera );
    },

    animate :  function animate() {
        console.log(this.container)
        var _this = this,
            timeOccur = _this.timeOcc(_this.speed);

        if (_this.dimensionChoice===1)
        {
            _this.k1 += _this.speed;
            _this.k1 = Math.round(_this.k1*1000) / 1000;

            _this.spike1.scale.y = (_this.k1 * _this.rangeLength) + _this.minLength;
            _this.spike2.scale.y = (_this.sigmoid(_this.k1,7) * _this.rangeLength) + _this.minLength;

            if ( _this.k1>=timeOccur[0] && _this.k1<=timeOccur[1])
            {
                _this.spikedBall.children[_this.spikeNum].children[0].geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( _this.radiusChange, 0.3, 1, 32 );
            }
            else {
                _this.spikedBall.children[_this.spikeNum].children[0].geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 0, 0.3, 1, 32 );
            }

            if (_this.k1 < 1)
            {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate);
            }
        }


        this.render();
    },

    domReady : function domReady () {
        this.init();
        this.animate();
    }
});}(window));
```

Comment: Hello, please read [ask]. Then create MCVE. Good luck!

Comment: I believe it should be `requestAnimationFrame( this.animate.bind(this) );`

Comment: Thanks gaigat, that works perfctly!